# Creating a trigger to update a previous ListPlot output with new data

Tags: plotting

Imagine I'm running a loop that's manipulating and changing elements in an array.  Is it possible for me to create a `ListPlot` output in my notebook that updates on command?

I'm imagining taking something like this:

```
testArray = Array[{0, 0} &, 10^3];
For[i = 1, i <= 10^3, i++,

  testArray[[i]] = {i, i};

  If[Mod[i, 10] == 0,
   Print[ListPlot[testArray, PlotRange -> All]];
  ];

];
```

And transforming it into something like this (with the imaginary command `fTriggerUpdateForPreviouslyExistingListPlot`):

```
testArray = Array[{0, 0} &, 10^3];
For[i = 1, i <= 10^3, i++,

  testArray[[i]] = {i, i};

  If[Mod[i, 10] == 0,
   fTriggerUpdateForPreviouslyExistingListPlot[{testArray}];
  ];

];
```

Here, `fTriggerUpdateForPreviouslyExistingListPlot` is some kind of switch that takes a listplot, say, in another notebook (within the context of the same kernel) or the current one, and plots the new data.

Is this possible?

---

The function `Monitor` comes close to what I'm looking for:

```
testArray = Array[{0, 0} &, 10^3];

Monitor[
   For[i = 1, i <= 10^3, i++,
     Pause[0.1];
     testArray[[i]] = {i, i};
   ];
,
ListPlot[testArray, PlotRange -> All]];

ListPlot[testArray, PlotRange -> All]
```

However, this updates whenever `testArray` changes, and not on a trigger.  I could create a separate `testArrayForMonitor` and move data from `testArray` to `testArrayForMonitor` to trigger an update, but this seems a bit of an odd thing to do, and incurs a significant overhead.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this, but you may try `Dynamic[ListPlot[testArray, PlotRange -> All], 
 TrackedSymbols -> p] testArray = Array[{0, 0} &, 10^3];
p = 0;
For[i = 1, i <= 10^3, i++, 
 testArray[[i]] = {i, i}; Pause[.01];
 p = Mod[i, 10];];`

Comment: The tracked symbol change triggers the update

Comment: @belisarius Yup, I just realized that after I posted my comment. =)

Comment: You could also use PrintTemporary[ListPlot[...]] function in your loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me whether my solution is OK, because I don't know what you mean by

> Is it possible for me [..] that updates **on command**?

Clearly, if the Kernel is busy evaluating one expression then other evaluations are usually queued. You can use a `DynamicModule` to update a graphic through a button or in a specific time interval. A simple example would be the following

```
testArray = Array[{0, 0} &, 10^3];
DynamicModule[{gr, update},
 update[] := gr = ListPlot[testArray, PlotRange -> All];
 update[];
 Panel[Column[{
    Button["Refresh", update[]],
    Dynamic[gr]
    }]
 ]
]
```

And then start you computation

```
For[i = 1, i <= 10^3, i++,
 Pause[.05];
 testArray[[i]] = {i, Sin[.01 i]*i};
]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

This should work with different kinds of triggers.

#### Edit:

To trigger it from inside the `For` loop, you can simply set a fake trigger variable and update the plot accordingly:

```
trigger = 0;
testArray = Array[{0, 0} &, 10^3];

Dynamic[(trigger; 
  ListPlot[testArray, PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {-500, 500}}]), 
 TrackedSymbols :> {trigger}]

For[i = 1, i <= 10^3, i++,
 Pause[.01];
 testArray[[i]] = {i, Sin[.01 i]*i};
 If[Mod[i, 50] === 0, trigger++]
 ]
```

Comment: Oh terrific - how can I trigger the refresh with a line of code in the For loop?  I'd like to refresh for Mod[i,10]==0 values, for example.

Comment: @RM1618 See my latest edit in the answer for this.

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  Why is it trigger++ instead of something like trigger+=1?

Comment: @RM1618 It really doesn't matter. `trigger` needs to be changed; that is the important thing. You can also use `trigger=i`.

Answer (score 1):

I like halirutan's answer, and its performance is superior because it avoids excessive refreshing, but I find it valuable to explore other approaches since there almost always is another in *Mathematica*, so here is a method that does not require modifying your loop, working much as `Monitor` does:

```
SetAttributes[lagDynamic, HoldAll]

lagDynamic[expr_, cond_] :=
  DynamicModule[{n, out = "waiting..."},
    Dynamic @ If[n != (n = cond), out = expr, out]
  ]
```

Example of use, borrowing halirutan's code:

```
lagDynamic[
  ListPlot[testArray, PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {-500, 500}}],
  Quotient[i, 50] (* refresh when this value changes *)
]

testArray = ConstantArray[0, {10^3, 2}];
Do[Pause[0.01]; testArray[[i]] = {i, Sin[.01 i]*i};, {i, 10^3}]
```

I think this is more convenient than the syntax you requested.